# hook before onAdd/onChange event adds dropped item to list

Tags: vue.draggable, vuedraggable

I have two lists (using cue-draggable), one source list and one configuration (sorted) list. When dropping item from source list onto configuration list I'd like to transform data before it is added to configuration list.

I am currently using the onChange event as I want access to actual JSON item where I use JS splice function to remove the already added item and then I transform data and insert into configuration list. This works but I'd prefer to transform data before any insertion into destination list.

```
onChange (evt) {
  if (evt.hasOwnProperty('added')) {
    var addedIndex = evt.added.newIndex
    if (addedIndex !== null) {
      var itemsToAdd = transform(evt.added.element)

      //remove new item inserted before receiving onChange
      this.recipe.stages.splice(addedIndex, 1)
      //Add transformed data
      this.recipe.stages.splice(addedIndex, 0, ...itemsToAdd)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From reading over the SortableJs and vue.draggable documentation and code, there's no way to do this.  A workaround (hack?) would be to use a computed property for your 'stages' array and pass it to draggable using v-model instead of the 'list' prop.  This tells draggable that the list is immutable.  So it will give you a brand new list whenever it makes changes.  You can take advantage of that.  Either do the replacement work in the setter, or write a noop/dummy setter and do the replacement work later once the change event is raised.

```
<draggable v-model="recipeStages" @change="onChange">
     ....
</draggable>


computed: {
    recipeStages: {
       get: function() { return this.recipe.stages;}
       set: function(value) {} //empty setter approach
    }
}
```

So, when the interaction is over and draggable calls 'onChange', you can do something like this:

```
onChange (evt) {
  if (evt.hasOwnProperty('added')) {
      var addedIndex = evt.added.newIndex;
      var transformed = transform(evt.added.element);
      this.recipe.stages.splice(addedIndex,0,transformed);
  }
}
```

The problem with this is obviously the empty/dummy setter.  It *feels* wrong, but shouldn't be a big deal.  You could also do a ton of work in that setter and figure out the difference between your current recipe stages and whatever draggable passed in.  You wouldn't need to bother with the onChange event.

Comment: Thanks @luis-carreras, I have since moved on from this project but will hopefully get back to it soon. Appreciate the feedback!